# Client Script : custom form update field

Tags: netsuite

Is it possible to retain all the data inside a form when the Custom form field is update? Currently, it reloads the page and all data will be gone.

THank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do :

On fields edit --> save field value to a cookie

And clear all those cookies on save.

That would be breaking normal functionality though...

Comment: This is also my solution. :) But I'm looking for alternatives

Comment: Try node to open a websocket and keep all data in a temporary database then use cookies to keep the session token. Would be the same as before, but without keeping sensitive data on the browser.

Problem is that unless you can cache everything on the browser it's hard to keep data across refreshes.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to test this, but you could make an array with all your field names, and do a validateField function (so it runs before the field is officially changed) where you get the values of every field in your array and store the values in a global array. Then have a fieldChanged function (so it runs after the field has changed) which loops back through resetting those values. This may most efficiently be done with an associative array